# django-haystack - filter based on query along with query for search term

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I am able to search using ?q='search term'. But my requirement is,  among the searched terms, I should be able to order them by price etc. filter by another field etc.

Will provide more information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [faceting](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faceting.html) which enables you to search on other fields of a model. Basically it comes down to defining the facets and then enabling the user to search for them, in addition to textual search as you're doing now with keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a SearchView, override the get_results method to do the extra processing you need on the SearchQuerySet like:

```
Class MySearchView(SearchView)
    #...
    def get_results(self):
        results = super(MySearchView, self).get_results()
        order = self.request.GET.get('order')
        if order:
            results = results.order_by(order)
        return results
```